# How to read custom format text file in C++

Tags: c++, file, loops

I'm writing small game.
I want to read objects positions from .txt file.
I want to write a code which reads files like this one (from .txt):

```
rock01
400.0 100.0 100.0
500.0 200.0 200.0
600.0 300.0 200.0
palm01
500.0 200.0 200.0
```

float 1 is x of object which is going to be created, second is y, third z.
The name (like 'rock01') is name of object to create.

My idea was to read object name and then while next line contains coordinates, not name of object, create new object with this coordinates.

So the code above should create 3 rocks and one palm.

My code

```
std::fstream file;//.txt file
file.open(filename, std::ios::in);

std::string word;//name of the object
while(file >> word)
{
if(word == "rock01")
        {
//and here I don't know how to read coordinates until next line is string
//so I read first...thing, and if it is float it creates new rock
            float x;
            while(file >> x)
            {
                rocks = new D_CRock;
                rocks->position.x = x;
                file >> rocks->position.y >> rocks->position.z
            }
        }
else if(word == "palm01") {
```

...
    }

}

This code is woriking but only for first object (it only creates 3 rocks, if i put code like this:

```
rock01
400.0 100.0 100.0 4.0 170.0
500.0 200.0 200.0 4.0 0.0
rock01
600.0 300.0 200.0 4.0 90.0
rock01
400.0 100.0 400.0 1.0 170.0
```

it will only create 2 rocks and ignore the rest.

How to read next sequence (from space to space like  'file >> someWord or someFloat' - not chars) without moving iterator?
How to read type of this sequence(to check if it could be float or only string)?

I want to know how I can do this in efficient way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your input file, you probably want to do something like the following:

- For each line

  - Check for non-numeric characters
  - If found, start a new object
  - else, parse coordinates and create a new instance

There are many different ways that you can do this, the following shows roughly the logic.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

bool contains_letter(std::string const& name)
{
    // There are many other ways to do this, but for the sake of keeping this answer short...
    return name.find_first_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ") != std::string::npos;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("filename.txt");
    // ...
    
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(file, line);
        
        if (contains_letter(line))
        {
            // ... Start a new object
        }
        else
        {
            // ... Parse the coordinates and add an instance
        }
    }
    
    // ...
}
```